# setMarginEnd is not working for RTL languages

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, right-to-left

I have a custom view (`TextView`). When the user clicks on the screen, the custom view will move based on touch (X position). For that I'm calling `setMarginLeft` on the custom view dynamically in LTR languages. If the default orientation is RTL then I'm calling `setMarginEnd` on the custom view. In LTR it is working fine but in RTL is not working. I think `setMarginEnd` is not working in RTL.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to support RTL in your app, you first need to add `android:supportsRtl="true"` to the `<application>` element in your `manifest` file.

and `setMarinStart` as well in your app.

Comment: I'm already using that attribute in manifest file. Layout change is working when language is changed.  setMarginStart is working but not setMarginEnd.